# The AWS stack removes RDS with the final snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

Some time ago, while deleting a stack, RDS was also deleted without leaving a final snapshot, now when RDS is deleted and a manual snapshot is created that is not deleted. What could be the reason?

I delete stack in this way:
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name name-of-the-stack

I did not find any similar problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation for AWS::RDS::DBCluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html) says:

> The default `DeletionPolicy` for `AWS::RDS::DBCluster` resources is **Snapshot**.

The [change history](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html) for the documentation has an entry for **August 18, 2017** that says:

> **The default DeletionPolicy is now Snapshot** for AWS::RDS::DBCluster resources and for AWS::RDS::DBInstance resources that don't specify the `DBClusterIdentifier` property.

So, you're not going crazy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is a possibility to change default DeletionPolicy to what was before?

Comment: You could add a [Deletion Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) that explicitly says `Delete`. (Or, apparently, you could specify a `DBClusterIdentifier`, per the above statement.)

Comment: Great. Thank you so much.